# ExtJS4: TreePanel Store is loading the json File again and again by Itemclick

Tags: javascript, json, tree, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have a json which has 3 main-menupoints. In the first menupoint, there is one submenu, so the menupoint 1 is no 'leaf'. When I click at the folder Symbol, the whole menu (the whole json file) is again under the submenu. So its infinity. Can someone help me with this please? THANK YOU!!

**Here are my files:**

**app/data/tree.json**

```
{
'result':
    [
        {
            "text": "Point1",
            'children':[
                {
                    "text": "SubPoint1",
                    'leaf':true
                },
            ]
        },
        {   "text": "Point2",
            'leaf':true
        },
        {
             "text": "Point3",
             'leaf':true
        },

]
```

}

**view/TreeMenu.js**

```
Ext.define('App.view.TreeMenu', {
extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
alias: 'widget.treemenu',
title:'Title',
store: 'TreeMenu'
```

});

**store/TreeMenu.js**

```
Ext.define('App.store.TreeMenu', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
requires: 'App.model.TreeMenu',
model: 'App.model.TreeMenu',
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'app/data/tree.json',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'result'
    }
}
```

});

**model/TreeMenu.js**

```
Ext.define('App.model.TreeMenu', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    { name: 'name', type: 'int', leaf:false, text:'name'},
    { name: 'value', type: 'string', leaf:false, text:'value'},
]
```

});

**controller/TreeMenu.js**

```
Ext.define('App.controller.TreeMenu', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
views: ['TreeMenu'],
models: ['TreeMenu'],   
stores: ['TreeMenu'],
onLaunch: function() {
    var treeStore = this.getTreeMenuStore();
    treeStore.load({
        //callback: this.onStationsLoad,
        scope: this
    });
},
refs: [{
    selector: 'tree',
    ref: 'treemenu'
}],
init: function() {
    this.control({
        'treemenu': {
            itemclick : this.treeItemClick  
        }
    });

},
treeItemClick : function(view, record) {
    console.log(record);
}
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to realize but your tree is actually working as designed :)

I created a fiddle for it to visualize: http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/auBTH/

Essentially every time you expand a node in a `tree` the default behavior is to load that node's children. That means the `store` will send a GET request to the server specified by the `proxy` url property. It sends the id of the node that you clicked on to expand so that the server side would use that id to run the query.

As you said you always return the same data set back and that is exactly what you are seeing: every time you expand a tree node an identical data set is appended to the tree as the children of the expanded node. One of the nodes you return is expandable .. and so you can repeat the process again :)

**EDIT**: upon further thought I found a separate issue that makes the node look for children nodes on the server instead of the already fetched sub nodes underneath. The issue is with how the reader is defined. In your original code you set json reader to parse data returned from the server specifying the `root` property set to **result**.
While this works on the initial load of data it also has an impact on how the children nodes are read. Essentially `root` config overrides the default **children** config. I corrected my previous example changing the `root` property to *children* - http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/auBTH/4/ now it works as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes thats right, but how can i prevent this? I don't want to load the same content again and again!

Comment: do you have other data to load? if so you need to send the id property for each node, and then handle getting data for that node id on the server side.

Comment: i have only this json file. Can you show me an example with this is node and than load it?!

Comment: Cool, that was ist! Had to rename the "result" to children. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!!!!

Comment: you are welcome, thanks for accepting the answer. if you find it useful don't forget to vote it up.

Comment: now you do:) enjoy stack exchange and don't forget to answer some questions!

Answer (score 0):

Do any children of Json tree has **"leaf : true"** ?

Maybe it's the problem...

-- EDIT:

I see that you have the leaf value.

Maybe can be this:

```
'children':[

                {
                    "text": "SubPoint1",
                    'leaf':true
                }-->, <------------------------- ERASE final comma.
            ]
```

Comment: yes, there are numerous extra commas that will choke IE browser and those should be corrected. However that is not the cause of the unexpected behavior. See my edit in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm it helps. The trick is in json format

```
var data = {
"result": [{
    "text": "Point1",
        "children": [{
```

The problem is the array of nodes is firstly under "results" and next under "children". These must be the same and used in root configuration in proxy

```
    var data = {
"result": [{
    "text": "Point1",
        "result": [{


root: 'result'
```

Michal