# How can I render nested JSON in Sencha?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I have a JSON file that seems proper formatted since when I load it into the online JSON viewer the tree renders:

[image]

Now I want to do something similar using Sencha ExtJS but the lower levels don't render:

[image]

Even though I rename all the nodes to the name "children" the problem is the same. From firebug I get this error when I try to expand the second level of the tree:

```
TypeError: records[i] is undefined


ns[i].viewRecordId = records[i].internalId;

ext-all-debug.js (line 60517)
```

What does the error mean? My code is

```
/*
 * File: app/controller/CheckNode.js
 *
 * This file was generated by Sencha Architect version 2.2.3.
 * http://www.sencha.com/products/architect/
 *
 * This file requires use of the Ext JS 4.0.x library, under independent license.
 * License of Sencha Architect does not include license for Ext JS 4.0.x. For more
 * details see http://www.sencha.com/license or contact license@sencha.com.
 *
 * This file will be auto-generated each and everytime you save your project.
 *
 * Do NOT hand edit this file.
 */

Ext.define('MyApp.controller.CheckNode', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    models: [
        'CheckNode'
    ],
    stores: [
        'CheckNodes'
    ],
    views: [
        'CheckedNodeTree'
    ],

    refs: [
        {
            ref: 'checkedTree',
            selector: 'checkedtree'
        }
    ],

    onButtonClick: function(button, e, eOpts) {
        var records = this.getCheckedTree().getView().getChecked(),
            names = [];

        Ext.Array.each(records, function(rec){
            names.push(rec.get('text'));
        });

        Ext.MessageBox.show({
            title: 'TODO',
            msg: names.join('<br />Not implemented'),
            icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO
        });    
    },

    init: function(application) {
        this.control({
            "button[action='getCheckedNodes']": {
                click: this.onButtonClick
            }
        });
    }

});

/*
 * File: app/model/CheckNode.js
 *
 * This file was generated by Sencha Architect version 2.2.3.
 * http://www.sencha.com/products/architect/
 *
 * This file requires use of the Ext JS 4.0.x library, under independent license.
 * License of Sencha Architect does not include license for Ext JS 4.0.x. For more
 * details see http://www.sencha.com/license or contact license@sencha.com.
 *
 * This file will be auto-generated each and everytime you save your project.
 *
 * Do NOT hand edit this file.
 */

Ext.define('MyApp.model.CheckNode', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'name'
        }
    ]
});
/*
 * File: app/store/CheckNodes.js
 *
 * This file was generated by Sencha Architect version 2.2.3.
 * http://www.sencha.com/products/architect/
 *
 * This file requires use of the Ext JS 4.0.x library, under independent license.
 * License of Sencha Architect does not include license for Ext JS 4.0.x. For more
 * details see http://www.sencha.com/license or contact license@sencha.com.
 *
 * This file will be auto-generated each and everytime you save your project.
 *
 * Do NOT hand edit this file.
 */

Ext.define('MyApp.store.CheckNodes', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.CheckNode'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            autoLoad: true,
            model: 'MyApp.model.CheckNode',
            storeId: 'CheckNodes',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data/tree.json'
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});

/*
 * File: app/view/CheckedNodeTree.js
 *
 * This file was generated by Sencha Architect version 2.2.3.
 * http://www.sencha.com/products/architect/
 *
 * This file requires use of the Ext JS 4.0.x library, under independent license.
 * License of Sencha Architect does not include license for Ext JS 4.0.x. For more
 * details see http://www.sencha.com/license or contact license@sencha.com.
 *
 * This file will be auto-generated each and everytime you save your project.
 *
 * Do NOT hand edit this file.
 */

Ext.define('MyApp.view.CheckedNodeTree', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.checkedtree',

    frame: true,
    height: 400,
    width: 640,
    title: 'Product Offerings',
    store: 'CheckNodes',
    displayField: 'name',
    lines: false,
    rootVisible: false,

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            viewConfig: {

            },
            dockedItems: [
                {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    dock: 'top',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            action: 'getCheckedNodes',
                            text: 'Add new'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }

});

/*
 * File: app/view/Viewport.js
 *
 * This file was generated by Sencha Architect version 2.2.3.
 * http://www.sencha.com/products/architect/
 *
 * This file requires use of the Ext JS 4.0.x library, under independent license.
 * License of Sencha Architect does not include license for Ext JS 4.0.x. For more
 * details see http://www.sencha.com/license or contact license@sencha.com.
 *
 * This file will be auto-generated each and everytime you save your project.
 *
 * Do NOT hand edit this file.
 */

Ext.define('MyApp.view.Viewport', {
    extend: 'MyApp.view.CheckedNodeTree',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

The beginning of the JSON file is

```
{"productOfferings":[{"@class":"BundledProductOffering","id":26,"name":"Mobile subscription with Internet access 2GB and iPad 32GB","description":"Joors 2GB mobile broadband and iPad 32GB","status":null,"brand":{"id":"Joors SE"},"validFor":{"startDateTime":1382514501359,"endDateTime":null},"productOfferings":[{"@class":"SimpleProductOffering","id":5,"name":"Ipad with 32 GB storage","description":"A iPad 32 GB Product Offering","status":"active","brand":{"id":"Joors SE"},"validFor":{"startDateTime":1382514501222,"endDateTime":null},"productSpecification":{"@class":"MobileProductSpecification","id":5,"name":"IPad","description":"","productNumber":"1234567","validFor":{"startDateTime":1382514501111,"endDateTime":null},"brand":{"id":"Joors SE"},"characteristics":null,"resourceSpecification":{"@class":"PhysicalDeviceSpecification","id":13,"resourceCapacity":null,"logicalResourceSpecification":null,"modelNumber":"A1460","partNumber":null,"skuNumber":null,"vendorName":"Apple","tags":[{"name":"hardware","value":"IPad"},{"name":"hardwareCategory","value":"tablet"},{"name":"hardwareBrand","value":"Apple"}],"descriptorId":null,"characteristics":[{"id":1,"name":"Color","description":null,"minCardinality":null,"maxCardinality":null,"validFor":null,"values":[{"valueType":"COLOR","defaultValue":false,"value":"WHITE","valueFrom":null,"valueTo":null,"unitOfMeasure":null,"validFor":{"startDateTime":1382514500714,"endDateTime":null}},{"valueType":"COLOR","defaultValue":false,"value":"BLACK","valueFrom":null,"valueTo":null,"unitOfMeasure":null,"validFor":{"startDateTime":1382514500713,"endDateTime":null}}],"valueType":null,"descriptorId":null},{"id":2,"name":"Storage size","description":null,"minCardinality":null,"maxCardinality":null,"validFor":null,"values":[{"valueType":"INTEGER","defaultValue":false,"value":"32","valueFrom":null,"valueTo":null,"unitOfMeasure":"GB","validFor":{"startDateTime":1382514500745,"endDateTime":null}},{"valueType":"INTEGER","defaultValue":false,"value":"16","valueFrom":null,"valueTo":null,"unitOfMeasure":"GB","validFor":{"startDateTime":1382514500745,"endDateTime":null}}],"valueType":null,"descriptorId":null}]},"serviceSpecification":null,"lifecycleStatus":null,"mobileNetworkOperator":{"id":2,"name":"Tele2 Sweden","mobileCountryCode":"240","mobileNetworkCode":"07","issuerIdentificationNumber":"894607","country":{"name":"Sweden","code":"SE"}},"tags":null,"descriptorId":null},"descriptorId":null,"tags":null,"productOfferingPrice":{"@class":"ProductOfferingPriceChargeDto","id":4,"description":"The price when buying a iPad with 32 GB memory together with a subscription","name":"iPad 32 GB product offering price","validFor":{"startDateTime":1382514501222,"endDateTime":null},"productSpecificationId":5,"productSpecificationCharacteristicValueUse":null,"resourceSpecificationCharacteristicValueUse":{"productOfferingReference":{"id":5,"name":"Ipad with 32 GB storage","sortOrder":null},"productSpecificationReference":{"id":5,"name":"IPad","sortOrder":null},"resourceSpecificationReference":{"id":13,"name":"iPad with Retina","sortOrder":null},"resourceSpecificationCharacteristicReference":{"id":2,"name":"Storage size","sortOrder":null},"resourceSpecificationCharacteristicValueDto":{"valueType":"INTEGER","defaultValue":false,"value":"32","valueFrom":null,"valueTo":null,"unitOfMeasure":"GB","validFor":{"startDateTime":1382514500745,"endDateTime":null}}},"serviceSpecificationCharacteristicValueUse":null,"money":{"amount":6890.00,"currency":"SEK"},"unitOfMeasure":{"amount":1,"units":"PIECE"}}},{"@class":"SimpleProductOffering","id":8,"name":"Mobile subscription with Sim Card and Internet access 2GB","description":"Mobile subscription with Sim Card and Internet access 2GB","status":"active","brand":{"id":"Joors SE"},"validFor":{"startDateTime":1382514501068,"endDateTime":null},"productSpecification":{"@class":"ProductSpecificationComposite","id":9,"name":"Mobile subscription with sim card and Internet access","description":"Mobile subscription with sim card and Internet access","productNumber":null,"validFor":{"startDateTime":1382514501068,"endDateTime":null},"brand":{"id":"Joors SE"},"characteristics":null,"resourceSpecification":null,"serviceSpecification":null,"productSpecifications":[{"@class":"MobileTelephonyProductSpecification","id":2,"name":"Mobile subscription with Sim Card","description":"This is the classic Subscription product of a Mobile Network totally void of Services, so it can only be used for accessing a HPLMN. Simply put a MSISDN + SIM","productNumber":null,"validFor":{"startDateTime":1382514501068,"endDateTime":null},"brand":{"id":"Joors SE"},"characteristics":null,"resourceSpecification":{"@class":"CompoundResourceSpecificationDto","id":15,"characteristics":null,"resourceSpecifications":[{"@class":"PhysicalSimCardResourceSpecification","id":1,"resourceCapacity":null,"logicalResourceSpecification":null,"modelNumber":null,"partNumber":"163","skuNumber":null,"vendorName":"Stralfors","name":"Sim Card","cardCarrier":"full-size","format":"Full size sim","uiccPartNumber":"","tags":null,"descriptorId":null,"characteristics":[]},{"@class":"MsisdnResourceSpecification","id":11,"resourceCapacity":null,"characteristics":[],"msisdnRegExp":".*","tags":null,"descriptorId":null}],"tags":null,"descriptorId":null,"resourceCapacity":null},"serviceSpecification":null,"lifecycleStatus":"active","mobileNetworkOperator":{"id":2,"name":"Tele2 Sweden","mobileCountryCode":"240","mobileNetworkCode":"07","issuerIdentificationNumber":"894607","country":{"name":"Sweden","code":"SE"}},"tags":[{"name":"subscription","value":"standard"}],"descriptorId":null},{"@class":"MobileProductSpecification","id":4,"name":"Mobile Internet access","description":"This is a GPRS Service for a Mobile Network Access Product for accessing Internet","productNumber":null,"validFor":{"startDateTime":1382514501106,"endDateTime":null},"brand":{"id":"Joors SE"},"characteristics":null,"resourceSpecification":null,"serviceSpecification":{"@class":"CompositeServiceSpecification","id":null,"name":"Joors Packet Data Access Service","description":null,"characteristics":null,"tags":null,"version":1,"serviceSpecifications":[{"@class":"MobilePacketDataNetworkAccessServiceSpecificationAtomic","id":1,"name":"Joors Domain Packet Data Access Service","description":null,"characteristics":[{"id":1,"name":"Quality of service max bandwidth","description":"Quality of service max bandwidth","minCardinality":null,"maxCardinality":null,"validFor":null,"values":[{"valueType":"FLOAT","defaultValue":false,"value":"10.0","valueFrom":null,"valueTo":null,"unitOfMeasure":"MBPS","validFor":null}],"valueType":"FLOAT","descriptorId":null}],"tags":null,"version":1,"sourceNetwork":"HPLMN","destinationNetwork":"joors.com","descriptorId":null,"mobileNetworkOperator":{"id":1,"name":"TeliaSoneraSE","mobileCountryCode":"240","mobileNetworkCode":"01","issuerIdentificationNumber":"894601","country":{"name":"Sweden","code":"SE"}}},{"@class":"MobilePacketDataNetworkAccessServiceSpecificationAtomic","id":2,"name":"Default Packet Data Access Service","description":null,"characteristics":[{"id":1,"name":"Quality of service max bandwidth","description":"Quality of service max bandwidth","minCardinality":null,"maxCardinality":null,"validFor":null,"values":[{"valueType":"FLOAT","defaultValue":false,"value":"10.0","valueFrom":null,"valueTo":null,"unitOfMeasure":"MBPS","validFor":null}],"valueType":"FLOAT","descriptorId":null}],"tags":null,"version":1,"sourceNetwork":"HPLMN","destinationNetwork":"*","descriptorId":null,"mobileNetworkOperator":{"id":1,"name":"TeliaSoneraSE","mobileCountryCode":"240","mobileNetworkCode":"01","issuerIdentificationNumber":"894601","country":{"name":"Sweden","code":"SE"}}},{"@class":"MobilePacketDataNetworkAccessServiceSpecificationAtomic","id":3,"name":"Fallback Packet Data Access Service","description":null,"characteristics":[{"id":2,"name":"Quality of service min bandwidth","description":"Quality of service min bandwidth","minCardinality":null,"maxCardinality":null,"validFor":null,"values":[{"valueType":"FLOAT","defaultValue":false,"value":"60.0","valueFrom":null,"valueTo":null,"unitOfMeasure":"KBPS","validFor":null}],"valueType":"FLOAT","descriptorId":null}],"tags":null,"version":1,"sourceNetwork":"HPLMN","destinationNetwork":"*","descriptorId":null,"mobileNetworkOperator":{"id":1,"name":"TeliaSoneraSE","mobileCountryCode":"240","mobileNetworkCode":"01","issuerIdentificationNumber":"894601","country":{"name":"Sweden","code":"SE"}}}],"descriptorId":null},"lifecycleStatus":null,"mobileNetworkOperator":{"id":1,"name":"TeliaSoneraSE","mobileCountryCode":"240","mobileNetworkCode":"01","issuerIdentificationNumber":"894601","country":{"name":"Sweden","code":"SE"}},"tags":null,"descriptorId":null}],"lifecycleStatus":"active","tags":null,"descriptorId":null},"descriptorId":null,"tags":null,"productOfferingPrice":{"@class":"CompositeProductOfferingPrice","id":10,"description":"Composite product offering price for Joors subscription with Internet access","name":"Joors subscription with Internet access","validFor":null,"productSpecificationId":null,"productSpecificationCharacteristicValueUse":null,"resourceSpecificationCharacteristicValueUse":null,"serviceSpecificationCharacteristicValueUse":null,"productOfferingPrices":[{"@class":"AllowanceProductOfferingPriceAlteration","id":9,"description":"","name":"Allowance for Joors subscription with 150 MB data and 60 kbps access to any domain","validFor":{"startDateTime":1382514501068,"endDateTime":null},"productSpecificationId":4,"productSpecificationCharacteristicValueUse":null,"resourceSpecificationCharacteristicValueUse":null,"serviceSpecificationCharacteristicValueUse":{"productOfferingReference":{"id":8,"name":"Mobile subscription with Sim Card and Internet access 2GB","sortOrder":null},"productSpecificationReference":{"id":4,"name":"Mobile Internet access","sortOrder":null},"serviceSpecificationReference":{"id":3,"name":"Fallback Packet Data Access Service","sortOrder":null},"serviceSpecificationCharacteristicReference":{"id":2,"name":"Quality of service min bandwidth","sortOrder":null},"serviceSpecificationCharacteristicValueDto":{"valueType":"FLOAT","defaultValue":false,"value":"60.0","valueFrom":null,"valueTo":null,"unitOfMeasure":"KBPS","validFor":null}},"money":{"amount":0.00,"currency":"SEK"},"unitOfMeasure":null},{"@class":"AllowanceProductOfferingPriceAlteration","id":8,"description":"","name":"Allowance for Joors subscription with 2.0 GB data and 10.0 mbps access to any domain","validFor":{"startDateTime":1382514501068,"endDateTime":null},"productSpecificationId":4,"productSpecificationCharacteristicValueUse":null,"resourceSpecificationCharacteristicValueUse":null,"serviceSpecificationCharacteristicValueUse":{"productOfferingReference":{"id":8,"name":"Mobile subscription with Sim Card and Internet access 2GB","sortOrder":null},"productSpecificationReference":{"id":4,"name":"Mobile Internet access","sortOrder":null},"serviceSpecificationReference":{"id":2,"name":"Default Packet Data Access Service","sortOrder":null},"serviceSpecificationCharacteristicReference":{"id":1,"name":"Quality of service max bandwidth","sortOrder":null},"serviceSpecificationCharacteristicValueDto":{"valueType":"FLOAT","defaultValue":false,"value":"10.0","valueFrom":null,"valueTo":null,"unitOfMeasure":"MBPS","validFor":null}},"money":{"amount":0.00,"currency":"SEK"},"unitOfMeasure":null},{"@class":"AllowanceProductOfferingPriceAlteration","id":7,"description":"","name":"Allowance for Joors subscription with unlimited amount of data and access to joors.com and 10.0 mbps quality of service","validFor":{"startDateTime":1382514501068,"endDateTime":null},"productSpecificationId":4,"productSpecificationCharacteristicValueUse":null,"resourceSpecificationCharacteristicValueUse":null,"serviceSpecificationCharacteristicValueUse":{"productOfferingReference":{"id":8,"name":"Mobile subscription with Sim Card and Internet access 2GB","sortOrder":null},"productSpecificationReference":{"id":4,"name":"Mobile Internet access","sortOrder":null},"serviceSpecificationReference":{"id":1,"name":"Joors Domain Packet Data Access Service","sortOrder":null},"serviceSpecificationCharacteristicReference":{"id":1,"name":"Quality of service max bandwidth","sortOrder":null},"serviceSpecificationCharacteristicValueDto":{"valueType":"FLOAT","defaultValue":false,"value":"10.0","valueFrom":null,"valueTo":null,"unitOfMeasure":"MBPS","validFor":null}},"money":{"amount":0.00,"currency":"SEK"},"unitOfMeasure":null}]}}],"descriptorId":{"id":115},"tags":[{"name":"subscription","value":"free"}],"productOfferingPrice":null}]}
```

When I put the above JSON in jsonviewer.stack.hu it renders one element with its children correctly, why can't Sencha do what other tools can do?

[image]

I have simplified the JSON that the tree should render and I've checked that it's correct:

```
{
    "productOfferings": [
        {
            "name": "Mobile subscription with Internet access 2GB and iPad 32GB",
            "description": "Joors 2GB mobile broadband and iPad 32GB",
            "productOfferings": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "Ipad with 32 GB storage",
                    "description": "A iPad 32 GB Product Offering",
                    "productSpecification": {
                        "id": 5,
                        "name": "IPad",
                        "description": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "name": "Mobile subscription with Sim Card and Internet access 2GB",
                    "description": "Mobile subscription with Sim Card and Internet access 2GB",
                    "productSpecification": {
                        "id": 9,
                        "name": "Mobile subscription with sim card and Internet access",
                        "description": "Mobile subscription with sim card and Internet access",
                        "productSpecifications": [
                            {
                                "id": 2,
                                "name": "Mobile subscription with Sim Card",
                                "description": "This is the classic Subscription product of a Mobile Network totally void of Services, so it can only be used for accessing a HPLMN. Simply put a MSISDN + SIM"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 4,
                                "name": "Mobile Internet access",
                                "description": "This is a GPRS Service for a Mobile Network Access Product for accessing Internet"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But the above is still too complicated for Sencha to render with my code. Why is this so difficult? This fiddle illustrates my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/auBTH/22/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the leafs of your tree like this:

```
{
    ... ,
    leaf: true

}
```

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-cfg-leaf

Also, define a root for your store

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.CheckNodes', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

requires: [
    'MyApp.model.CheckNode'
],

constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        autoLoad: true,
        root: 'productOfferings',
        model: 'MyApp.model.CheckNode',
        storeId: 'CheckNodes',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            root: 'productOfferings',
            url: 'data/tree.json'
        }
    }, cfg)]);
}
```

});

Comment: It can't be done. I can't change the JSON and I can't set a root with Sencha Architect. I know the JSON is properly formatted sine other tools than Sencha can load the tree. Now I don't know what to do since Sencha Architect won't let it to work. I can't set a root and II don't expect that to work even if I could. I did set a defaultRootProperty though I don't even know what that means since the documentation sucks.

Comment: The root property checks where to look for more data when you expand something in your tree.
You should check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423122/extjs4-treepanel-store-is-loading-the-json-file-again-and-again-by-itemclick?rq=1) question for more information.
It is the exactly the same problem you had and was solved by setting the root according to the data

Comment: I made a fiddle and it's absolutely not working at all: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/cmzyH/ while many other online JSON viewer directly can render a tree from the JSON data. Why can't Senca do what other project can do?

Comment: What's wrong about that tree in your fiddle? It seems perfectly fine...
Also, with such a complex JSON you may be better off with a file which only returns the elements you need, like in [this](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/tree/xml-tree.html) example, the get-nodes.php reads just the required data from the xml-file

Comment: Please look again:http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/cmzyH/6/ It now has what is supposed to be just one JSON elements with its children. It is trying to render the tree but it breaks. Since other tools such as http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ can render this JSON directly with absolutely no configuration, why can't Sencha do it? I know the JSON is ridiculously complex but I've hortened it down and other tools can render it so we are suprised that Sencha can't do what other tools easily can.

Comment: I guess it can't render the tree because the provided JSON is incorrect, http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ also alerts me that it is an Invalid JSON variable

Comment: The provided JSON in the fiddle is correct according to jsonviewer.stack.hu. When I copy the variable there it renders the tree the way I want to do it with Sencha.

Comment: Tried to get the fiddle working and it will display the tree if you remove the last } of the JSON, but in general you're right, ExtJS cannot really make it work the way you want to. I guess the only possibility to get it working is to send the id you're expanding and return the data accordingly...

Comment: Did you manage to get the names written or just render the tree? When I remove the last } of the JSON it doen't render anything. The fiddle I did does not display the names of the levels and it can't do just a simple view of the entire tree. http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/cmzyH/6/

Comment: Technically you are able to set [displayField](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-cfg-displayField) but you used 'name' which is one of the few variables you should not use, because ExtJS uses them somewhere

Comment: That was also impossible. I tried to set displayField to 'name' which worked in Sencha Architect while in the fiddle nothing is working, not even entering code in the fiddle is working for me since the jfiddle is also completely bugged out. Nothing works and Sencha has made me waste my time for several days claiming to be a "leading" framework when they can't even render a nested tree.

Comment: As I already pointed out, you should try not to load the whole JSON once, but just the pieces you need when you expand

Comment: Niklas, sorry for updating this so late, but I've been working on a new project and read the documentation for the Ext.data.reader.Reader which provides a perfect example of how to load nested data.
I'm so sorry I haven't seen this when answering this question ._.
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader

Comment: Thanks for the help. We ended up coding a custom JSON response that wasn't nested and it's working well. I named all the nodes "children" and then it was much easier to work with. My structure was even more complicated than in the example and an engineer at Sencha said that I could write a "custom Ajax proxy" in javascript but that would have been way too difficult. More natural to do it serverside so I wrote Java classes that can output a simplified JSON using Jackson and then the solution become rather nice.

Comment: Okay, nice you found a working solution. I just felt bad, because I said that your problem couldn't be solved with pure ExtJS and then I read this... ^^